# What is standard approach to add and manage stylesheets (CSS) files in Drupal 8 with Libraries?

Tags: drupal-8, theming, lib

When developing modules or theme for Drupal, there inevitably comes a time when we may need to include an external CSS or Javascript plugin or library for our project.

Drupal assets management is a little complex and make me confused, I read
 [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) and 
[Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module), 
but it doesn't explain that clearly and there are some question about it yet.

How are processed these libraries and stylesheets added to a web pages? are they added in the order of SMACSS category (base, layout, component, state,theme)?
For example consider the following structure:
**ThemeName.libraries.yml**

```
library-A:
  css:
    # The SMACSS category.
    base:
      # The path to the css file.
      assets/css/stylesheets-1.css: {}
    theme:
      assets/css/stylesheets-2.css: {}

library-B:
  css:
    base:
      # The path to the css file.
      assets/css/stylesheets-3.css: {}
    theme:
      assets/css/stylesheets-4.css {}
```

**In library-A or B (Each alone)**: how i should define category? First should come `Theme` and then `base` or reverse? What is criteria?

**In totally library-A and B**: witch of them Load first? library-A or B? what respective is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1: more info [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1887918#separate-concerns), basically theme will overwrite base although weights are inverted; now that is a guideline not a rulle so it really depends on what are you writing

for 2: it really depends on where and how you load them,

ex to load libraries it inverted order:

- in theme

  libraries:

  - 'mytheme/library-B' //replace bullet with "- "
  - 'mytheme/library-A' //replace bullet with "- "
- in template

  {{ attach_library('mytheme/library-B') }}
  {{ attach_library('mytheme/library-A') }}
- in module

  $types['element']['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/library-B';
  $types['element']['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/library-A';

Comment: Thank you so much, For your help ;)